# PL/SQL: How to compare 2 sets of data

Tags: sql, oracle

if I have 2 rows stored in a table with just 3 columns (ID, Name, Salary) to make it simple:

```
Row 1: 123, Sal, 1000
Row 2: 123, Sal, 1001
```

How can I write a pl/sql program to compare row 1 data (column by column) with Row 2?
Of course in my example, there will be a lot more columns and rows. I just need to be able to compare 2 rows (column by column) and verify they have the same values.

Comment: Please provide sample output for what you want as the result of your query.

Comment: How do you know which two rows to compare if there are more than 2?  What are the results that you would want?

Comment: are you more interested in ease of implementation or efficiency of execution?

Answer (score 1):

For such a general form of question, I suppose [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) would be the answer.
So, in your terms:

```
  select ID, Name, Salary from Salaries
  group by ID, Name, Salary
  having count(*) > 1
```

This sql statement will output all records with equal "ID, Name, Salary" field values (due 'having' condition).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start that gets you two rows side-by-side.

```
select r1.id
      ,r1.name
      ,r1.salary
      ,r2.id
      ,r2.name
      ,r2.salary      
  from your_data r1
      ,your_data r2
 where r1.id = 1
   and r2.id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use minus. if therows are not the same it will return a record. if they are the same nothing will return

```
select name, salary
  from table
 where id = 1

minus

select name, salary
  from table
 where id = 2
```